# Where are the `*.journal` files for a given unit?

Tags: linux, systemd, systemd-journald

I have a systemd service unit for sshd:

```
$ systemctl status sshd
* ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-09-30 18:54:10 UTC; 6s ago
  Process: 13923 ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 13918 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6287 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6296 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           `-6296 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Sep 30 18:54:10 machine systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Sep 30 18:54:10 machine sshd[6296]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Sep 30 18:54:10 machine sshd[6296]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Sep 30 18:54:10 machine systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
```

I have some `*.journal` files that it wrote:

```
$ find /var/log/journal -type f -name 'system@*.journal' -exec grep -l 'OpenBSD' {} +
/var/log/journal/0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef/system@0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef-000000000100bfdd-0005ac0c092a655f.journal
/var/log/journal/0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef/system@0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef-000000000102d6c3-0005ac2251abe7d9.journal
/var/log/journal/0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef/system@0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef-00000000010fc6d5-0005ac9be551a106.journal
/var/log/journal/0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef/system@0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef-0000000000e043b9-0005aad981c2d167.journal
/var/log/journal/0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef/system@0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef-00000000010d9bf1-0005ac875e1241e7.journal
```

Given the former, how do I find the latter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Journal files are not sorted by unit.  The unit issuing the journal entry is simply metadata associated with the entry.  Journal files are also not always in `/var`.  They could also be found in `/run` if configured as non-persistent.

The correct way to extract journal entries for a specific unit is to use `journalctl -u <unit_name>` or to use the [`sd-journal` API](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd-journal.html). In addition, the journal is a binary file so it's not exactly in a format that is parse-friendly.  I'm not even sure that the internal format of the journal follows a stable specification.  `journalctl` or the API is definitely the way to read these files.

If you are asking this question to back-up (or send for troubleshooting) a specific file, you'll need to treat all of these files as a single unit.

---

Since you asked specifically about the file-naming convention of these journal files, I spent some time investigating this.  After a fresh boot, the only file in `/run/log/journal` was `/run/log/journal/c13e4a2f54334a95891a6a471db3b7e0/system@edd0c14e44a240038601194807d5c28e-0000000000000001-0005b08ccb2c37b3.journal`.

I broke that down into the following to try and understand the naming convention:

```
/run/                                  <-- run/var
  log/journal/                         <-- standard location 
    c13e4a2f54334a95891a6a471db3b7e0/  <-- _MACHINE_ID
    system@                            <-- system/user
    edd0c14e44a240038601194807d5c28e-  <-- Some bus/boot/session ID?
    0000000000000001-                  <-- Sequence number (also looks like offsets as 4-KB blocks in hex)
    0005b08ccb2c37b3                   <-- Timestamp (time since epoch in hex)
    .journal                           <-- Extension
```

When I look at a machine which has been running for a while, all `system@*.journal` files are 80M while all `user@*.journal` files are 8.0M.  With such consistent sizing, it really suggests that the file splits are simply log rotations.  I can also confirm that by looking at the modification dates (as we go forward in sequence, I see the dates increasing).

---

To figure some of these things out (like `_MACHINE_ID`) I had to look into the raw meta-data associated with a journal entry.  There is more meta-data than what you can get with `journalctl`.  I wrote a quick program with the sd-journal API and printed `"Hello"` from a service.  I found it in the journal with the following data.  It's amazing how much meta-data is associated with each `printf`.

```
_UID=0
_GID=0
_CAP_EFFECTIVE=3fffffffff
_TRANSPORT=stdout
_STREAM_ID=2ee82c395817429b975770acb1306d11
SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=counter
_PID=6523
_COMM=counter
_EXE=/usr/local/bin/counter
_CMDLINE=/usr/local/bin/counter
_SYSTEMD_CGROUP=/system.slice/counter.service
_SYSTEMD_UNIT=counter.service
_SYSTEMD_INVOCATION_ID=711962f5d7bf487b9a262b824c297a42
MESSAGE=Hello
PRIORITY=6
SYSLOG_FACILITY=3
_BOOT_ID=bf0d96cbab2144e3a8544b0e8a0eacc6
_MACHINE_ID=c13e4a2f54334a95891a6a471db3b7e0
_HOSTNAME=simswe24
_TRANSPORT=journal
_SELINUX_CONTEXT=unconfined
```

---

If you're interested in the sd-journal program I wrote to investigate this, it's here:

```
// Compile with `gcc journalctl.c -lsystemd`
#include <systemd/sd-journal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    // Open the log
    sd_journal* journal;

    if ( sd_journal_open(&journal, SD_JOURNAL_LOCAL_ONLY) < 0 )
    {
        return 1; // Couldn't open journal
    }

    // Subscribe to specific logs:
    // Messages from the service itself
    int r = sd_journal_add_match(journal, "_SYSTEMD_UNIT=counter.service", 0);
    r = r ? r : sd_journal_add_disjunction(journal);
    
    // Messages from PID 1 (systemd) about this service
    r = r ? r : sd_journal_add_match(journal, "_PID=1", 0);
    r = r ? r : sd_journal_add_match(journal, "UNIT=counter.service", 0);
    r = r ? r : sd_journal_add_disjunction(journal);

    if ( r < 0 )
    {
        return 1; // Could not subscribe to all journal entries
    }

    r = sd_journal_seek_head(journal);
    if ( r < 0 )
    {
        return 1; // Problem finding the head of the log
    }


    // Read the log
    int skip_seek=1;
    while( skip_seek || (sd_journal_next(journal) > 0 ) ) 
    {
        const void* data = 0;
        size_t length;
        skip_seek = 0;

        sd_journal_restart_data(journal);

        SD_JOURNAL_FOREACH_DATA(journal, data, length)
        {
            printf("%s\n", data);
        };
    }

    sd_journal_close(journal);

    return 0;
}
```